# Is there a quick way to change the database connection name in all project files in asp.net Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Is there a quick way to change the database connection name in all project files in asp.net Visual Studio?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link provided by jhambright.In a project, it is more common to encapsulate entity classes that operate on the database.

```
 public class DBHelper
 {
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();//The object connection responsible for connecting to the data
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();//Object command responsible for executing SQL statements
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=student;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to the database
    /// </summary>
    private void ConnectDataBase()
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; //Specify the connection string
        if(connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SQL statement to be executed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    public void ExecuteSQL(string commandString)
    {
        ConnectDataBase();//Connect to the database
        command.Connection = connection;//Specify the connection
        command.CommandText = commandString;//Specify the SQL command to be operated
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();//Close the database connection
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close the existing database connection
    /// </summary>
    private void CloseConnection()
    {
       connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Modify the database connection name:

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()
```

To operate the database in the project:

```
  DBHelper helper = new DBHelper()
```